# hide elements based on a filter

Tags: jquery, filtering

I'm new to jquery and I'm trying to do the following :
I have a page with lots of images. I added a textbox, with *onchange* calling this function :

```
function filter() {
    var filter = $("#filter").val()
    $('.photo').show();  
    if (filter != '') $('.photo').find('.'+filter).hide();

}
```

The point being to only show images that have "filter" *somewhere* in their class name.

**EDIT**

```
<a name="test"></a>

<h3>Tests</h3><br />
<img class="photo livre_gang_leader.jpg" src="/images/test/livre_gang_leader.jpg" />
<img class="photo stephen_king_fatal.jpg" src="/images/test/stephen_king_fatal.jpg" />
<img class="photo livres_millenium.jpg" src="/images/test/livres_millenium.jpg" /></a>
<img class="photo martin_page_stupide.jpg" src="/images/test/martin_page_stupide.jpg" />
<img class="photo Civilization-V-Title.jpg" src="/images/test/Civilization-V-Title.jpg" />
<br /><br />
```

**EDIT**

```
<form onSubmit="javascript:filter()">
    <input type="textbox" placeholder="Filtre" id="filter" />
    <input type="submit" value="filtrer">
</form><br />
```

Comment: it may be $('.photo').find('.'+filter) that have to be replaced by $('.photo .'+filter), but without the html markup, it's hard to tell. Can you provide it too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you also want to match for classname fragments (e.g. to show "apple" when typing "ple"), consider using the [attribute contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector `'[class*="'+filter+'"]'`. Combined with the answers above:

```
function filter() {
    var filter = $("#filter").val();
    var photos = $('.photo');
    photos.show();  
    if (filter != '') photos.not('[class*="'+filter+'"]').hide();    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use jQuery's [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) method instead of `.find()`:

```
function filter() {
    var filter = $("#filter").val(),
        photos = $('.photo');  // don't forget to cache your selectors!

    photos.show();  

    if (filter != '') 
        photos.filter('.'+filter).hide();    
}
```

If you want to show elements based on this filter, just swap the places of `.hide()` and `.show()` in the code, so that all photos are hidden and then filtered ones are shown (instead of all photos shown and filtered ones hidden).

Answer (score 4):

this way you're filtering classes, if you want to filter text you do this

```
$(".photo").hide();
$(".photo:contains("+filter+")").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you are wanting to show the ones that are named with the filter value you will want to use `.not()` instead of `.filter()`

```
function filter() {
    var filter = $("#filter").val();
    $('.photo').show();  
    if (filter != '') $('.photo').not('.'+filter).hide();    
}
```

Comment: You could also keep `filter()` and swap around the `hide()` and `show()`.